# Inequality challenge

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

I was studying inequations when I encountered this problem here.

How can I find a region of values for m where this inequation is true?

$$-3<\frac{x^2+mx-2}{x^2-x+1}>2$$

Thanks

Comment: This inequality reduces to the center portion being greater than $2$

Comment: Did you mean $< 2$?

Comment: No. > 2 its how the problem shows. But I understand your question. Would make more sense if the equation in the middle were between -3 and 2, right?

Answer (score 0):

you have to solve two polynomial equations.

It's obvious that $x^{2}-x+1>0$. Then the inequality becomes:

\begin{equation}
-3x^{2}+3x-3<x^{2}+mx-2<2x^{2}-2x+1
\end{equation}

which is easy to solve, see for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function